# Thumbnails not viewing quite the way I want?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am making amends to a Blogger site for a friend and it is custom built so it doesn't really fit under the blogger help section.

I'm hoping its a specific HTML/CSS question and someone here might be able to help.

I am setting up a menu list using thumbnails from posts already up. So far I have got the thumbnails working, but I can't seem to get the layout right even adjusting the CSS and i'm not sure what I am missing.

Basically I would like the thumbnails to align side by side with an option to include the title below them centered and if necessary over 2 lines.

My problems are:
1. I can't seem to get the thumbnails to sit side by side.
2. I can't seem to lessen the vertical space between thumbnails
3. I would like to make the text sit underneath the thumbnails if possible. 
4. Finally I would like the fix the left alignment of thumbnails so they align with the title above.

This is the page in question: http://www.cakeandtravels.com/p/breakfast.html
(i would like to post a pic but it won't let me.)

This is the CSS I'm using so far:

```
/* Recent posts by labels
--------------------------------- */ 
img.label_thumb{
float:left;
border: none; 
background: none;
height:120px;width:120  px;
margin:0 2px 2px 0px;
padding:0px;
}

ul.label_with_thumbs {
width:auto;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:2px;
border: none;
height: 800px;
}

img.label_thumb:hover{
border: none;
background: none; 
}

.label_with_thumbs{
float:left;
display: inline;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:5px;
background:none;
}

ul.label_with_thumbs li{
text-align: center;
text-wrap: auto;
text-indent: 5px;
line-height:140px;
margin:0;
padding: 4px 0 5px;
width:100%
}
```

Its then linked to a series of Javascript and imported into the specific page using that.
(i am really hoping that is not where the problem lies as its a bit out of my knowledge base!)

Any help at all or if you require any further information to help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks
Angie

Comment: Did you open your browser's console to see if the request for the image file failed?

Comment: Hi Domi, 
My images are calling in fine, its actually more just the actual design that I am trying to tweek.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, without any of your css, I just put this :

```
ul.label_with_thumbs li {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
height: 110px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top; }

img.label_thumb {
margin: auto;
}
```

That resolve some of your needs for me. This is [my version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcsNG.png), it stay some things to improve to perfectly fit your wishes (like adjust size of the images,..), it's just a beta version.

And like Domi said, you'll have a lot of help from your console. F12 to display it, and you can change the css inside your page for trying to improve it.